# How to restrict entries in 'Select Language' dropdown list?

Tags: fullcalendar

I use [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) in a site of mine:
[image]
I'd like to restrict the content of 'Select Language' dropdown list to specific entries (let's say English, French and Finnish).

I couldn't find how to do that.
Any help?

Comment: the "select language" dropdown you've shown is not a part of fullCalendar directly. Presumably this is done by some extra code. Without seeing that code, we cannot tell you how to change it.

Comment: You're completely right! It is in a Drupal module implementing fullCalendar.
Though you can see something similar [here](https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar/3.9.0/demos/locales.html).
And I found the solution!

Comment: Agreed but in that demo the dropdown is again provided by some custom HTML outside the calendar - if you look at the source you can see it's `<div id='top'>

    Locales:
    <select id='locale-selector'></select>

  </div><div id='calendar'></div>` - the dropdown is simply above the calendar. And there's some extra custom JS as well to update fullCalendar's locale settings (via the API) every time the dropdown value changes. Anyway, glad you were able to fix your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said to @ADyson, I use FullCalendar implemented by a Drupal module.
Finally, I updated this piece of code in `fullcalendar_view.js`
adding `if (localeCode=="en" || localeCode=="fi" || localeCode=="fr") {`

```
            if (drupalSettings.languageSelector) {
                 // Build the locale selector's options.
                $.each($.fullCalendar.locales, function (localeCode) {
if (localeCode=="en" || localeCode=="fi" || localeCode=="fr") {
                  $('#locale-selector').append(
                    $('<option/>')
                      .attr('value', localeCode)
                      .prop('selected', localeCode == drupalSettings.defaultLang)
                      .text(localeCode)
                  );
}
                });
                // When the selected option changes, dynamically change the calendar option.
                $('#locale-selector').on('change', function () {
                  if (this.value) {
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'locale', this.value);
                  }
                });
            }
```

and it works!